# Inherit multiple objects into a class

Tags: java

I have been given an assignment to make a java program to model computers.
I was told to make three classes in the java program, called RAM, Harddrive and Processor, which hold information regarding the RAM's size, manufacturer partcode etc.. and similar with the harddrive and processor. I was then told to make another class called advanced computer, where the advanced computer class has fields which hold the RAM, Harddrive and processor objects.

I believe to do this I would need to use either the extends function in java, but as far as I am aware there is no way for a class to extend more than one object/class.

I have tried letting RAM etc.. classes extend the advanced computer class and then create individual constructor for RAM etc.. in the advanced computer class, but it seem's like I am on the wrong path..

This is the part of the RAM class, I have started on the advanced computer class and commented out most of it as it was causing the functionality of the rest of the program to crash

```
public class RAM {
private String Make;
private String Model;
private int Size;

//Constructor for RAM
public RAM(String Make, String Model, int Size ){
    this.Make = Make;
    this.Model = Model;
    this.Size = Size;
}

//getters and setter for variables of RAM
```

Thanks for any help given!

Comment: To write a new class that has fields referring to other classes, you do NOT need the `extends` keyword. Fields do not require inheritance.

Comment: But I want these to be used as objects in the new class, not just individual fields! How would I go about doing that? Cheers!

Comment: A field can be of a type Object and also a defined class as RAM. So declaring `private RAM Ram;` in your advanced computer is perfectly fine

Comment: Now you might have have some base class, say StorageDevice which has the make,model, size, seria #, etc... But and even more basic Device class to have make, model, serial #... But for the last 15 to 20 years having deep inheritance hierarchies is considered a bad taste, if not outright anti pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He's not asking you to extend any of those classes (RAM, HardDrive, Processor). Think about it logically; ie. in the real world. A computer contains RAM, Hard Drive, and Processor right? So create a class that has those 3 components:

```
public class AdvancedComputer {

    private Ram ram;
    private HardDrive hdd;
    private Processor cpu;

    public AdvancedComputer (Ram ram, HardDrive hdd, Processor cpu) {
        this.ram = ram;
        this.hdd = hdd;
        this.cpu = cpu;
    }
}
```

When you come across an assignment like this and feel lost, try to take a step back and think of it in terms of the real world. How are things designed in the real world? More often than not, mimicking that in your code is what is required.

Comment: Thanks this helped along with the comments! Completely understand it now!